# Oracle How to get amount of commits table?

Tags: sql, oracle, insert, commit, dml

Is there any information about amount of `inserts`/`updates`/`deletes` to the certain table, for example, from last week?
It will be great if there will be statistics:

```
  TABLE      | INSERTS | UPDATES | DELETES   |      DAY
Test_table   |   100   |     200 |    200    |   14/02/2017
Test_table   |   105   |     300 |    50     |   15/02/2017
Test_table   |   400   |     300 |    50     |   16/02/2017
```

Or:

```
 TABLE       | COMMITS |      DAY
Test_table   |   100   |    14/02/2017
Test_table   |   105   |    15/02/2017
Test_table   |   400   |    16/02/2017
```

Comment: What do you need this for?

Comment: @BobC, I want to know in which day there was a big amount of dml-s to my table and which sql_id did it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such table as you expected but DML/DDL modifications are recorded and displayed through DBA/USER/ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS views as shown below.

```
SQL> desc all_tab_modifications;
 Name                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 TABLE_OWNER                        VARCHAR2(128)
 TABLE_NAME                     VARCHAR2(128)
 PARTITION_NAME                     VARCHAR2(128)
 SUBPARTITION_NAME                  VARCHAR2(128)
 INSERTS                        NUMBER
 UPDATES                        NUMBER
 DELETES                        NUMBER
 TIMESTAMP                      DATE
 TRUNCATED                      VARCHAR2(3)
 DROP_SEGMENTS                      NUMBER
```

> #### ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS
>
> ALL_TAB_MODIFICATIONS describes tables accessible to the current user that have been modified since the last time statistics were gathered on the tables.

As @MT0 said, you can create new table to store this information on daily basis before gathering new statistics.

Comment: To get the OP's table structure you could build a daily job that copies this information to a logging table and then re-gathers statistics on the tables you are monitoring.

Comment: @MT0: Yes. Thank you.

Comment: @JSapkota, can I link this table to dba_hist_active_sess_history to get more information about inserts? I want to know why there were so many commits to my table last friday.

Comment: @Jdzel: As long as you have joining method you can join and get the required information. There is no relationship between these two views.